# connect 2 terraform remote states

Tags: terraform, backend

I'm working on a terraform task, where I need to connect two terraform s3 backends. We have a 2 repos for our tf script. The main one is for creating dev/qa/prod envs and the other one is for managing users/policies required for the first script.

We use s3 as the backend and I want to connect both the backend together so they can take ids/names from each other with out hardcoding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a backend A  / terraform project A with your ids/names:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

output "names" {
  value = [ "bob", "jim" ]
}
```

In your other terraform project B you can refer to the above backend A as a data source:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "remote_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Then in the terraform project B you can fetch the outputs of the remote state with names/ids:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.names
```

Comment: This is working for me.  Thank you very much. @pijemcolu